# python regex matching only if the groups are between a special character

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm working with a dataframe with some medicines and I want extract the dosages from a full sentence taken from the product description.

Example of what I want:

```
Dexamethasonacetat 5 mg/10 mg, Lidocain-HCl 1H2O 30 mg/60 mg
#['5mg/10mg','30mg/60mg']

Anakinra 120 mg /-20 g /-12mg gentechnologisch hergestellt aus E. coli. 10mg pack
#['120mg/20g/12mg']
```

I can extract the dosage using `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*(g|mg|)`, which gets me:

```
Dexamethasonacetat 5 mg/10 mg, Lidocain-HCl 1H2O 30 mg/60 mg
#['5mg','10mg','30mg','60mg']

Anakinra 120 mg /-20 g /-12mg gentechnologisch hergestellt aus E. coli. 10mg pack
#['120mg','20g','12mg','10mg]
```

It would be easier to do this if `/` only happens once, but it can happen multiple times..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get those matches using a pattern, and then after process it to remove the spaces and the hyphens

```
-?\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*m?g(?:\s*/\s*-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*m?g)+\b
```

**Explanation**

- `-?` Match an optional hyphen
- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*` Match 1+ digits with optional decimal part
- `\s*m?g` Match optional whitespace chars, optional `m` and `g`
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole

  - `\s*/\s*` Match `/` between optional whitespace chars
  - `-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*m?g` Match the same digits pattern as before
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat 1+ times to match at least a part with a forward slash
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tGmROy/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/JmTEdz).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"-?\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*m?g(?:\s*/\s*-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*\s*m?g)+\b"

strings = [
    "Dexamethasonacetat 5 mg/10 mg, Lidocain-HCl 1H2O 30 mg/60 mg",
    "Anakinra 120 mg /-20 g /-12mg gentechnologisch hergestellt aus E. coli. 10mg pack"
]

for s in strings:
    print([re.sub(r"[\s-]+", "", m) for m in re.findall(pattern, s)])
```

Output

```
['5mg/10mg', '30mg/60mg']
['120mg/20g/12mg']
```